# Is it possible to Copy Subregion of One 2D Array to Another Using numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have some 2d arrays using numpy, and I want to copy subregions from one into another. For example, if I start with:

```
dest = numpy.zeros((4, 4))
# array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
src = numpy.ones((4, 4))
# array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
#   [1., 1., 1., 1.],
#   [1., 1., 1., 1.],
#   [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

I want to somehow say that the `src` should be copied into `dest` at `(2,1)`, such that source would then look like:

```
 array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 1.],
   [0., 0., 1., 1.],
   [0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```

Or if `(-3, 0)`, then:

```
 array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I can do the good old fashioned double index loop to do this, but I was hoping numpy had some clever magic that did it. I looked at `take`, but couldn't see how to make that the tool for this job.

Comment: just use assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these can be accomplished with `numpy` indexing.  To understand how this works, the [documentation is always your friend](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Your first case:

```
dest[1: ,2:] = src[1: ,2:]

array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 1.],
   [0., 0., 1., 1.],
   [0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```

Your second case: (You indicated column -3 but your results indicate -4)

```
dest[:, -4] = src[:, -4]

array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```